# Ajax data not evaluating to empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've just made the upgrade to jQuery 1.10.x and apart from several minor method changes, everything has gone according to plan, with the exception of Ajax:

```
function get_folders_hierarchy_manual (object_folders) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "path/" + object_folders.child,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (element) {
            if (element!=null) {
                for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                    // Do things.
                }
            } else {
                // Do something else.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Previously, the "do something else" part would trigger when there was no data returned from the data source. However, since the upgrade, this no longer evaluates to being empty.

I've even tried using the error parameter as an adjunct to the success, but that doesn't do anything either.

I've set a watch on the element expression and it isn't emptied between queries. In all honesty, I don't know what it did beforehand as I had no reason to look!

Any ideas?

Just to be clear, element is an array of objects, and it always evaluates to true; having a length and containing objects.

Comment: Can't say I'm sure it ever returned `null` when there was no data, but try expanding the condition to any falsy value `if ( !element ) { ..`

Comment: Well, what is the value of `element` now when it was `null` (or `undefined`) before? Have a look and then test for that value.

Comment: Adeneo, that just stops the whole thing in its tracks.

Comment: As you're iterating, the more proper thing to do would probably be to check if it's an array with Array.isArray or see if it has length before you stick it in a loop.

Comment: Felix, it's an array of objects, but it's as if it's remembering each array between actions. I have cache set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try  data truthify

```
 success: function (element) {
            if (element) {
                for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                    // Do things.
                }
            } else {
                // Do something else.
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's the number of elements for the previous folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was a combination of removing the conditional and adding an error parameter:

```
function get_folders_hierarchy_manual (object_folders) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "path/" + object_folders.child,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (element) {
            for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                // Do things.
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            // Do something else.
        }
    });
}
```